# Add user_id value to urls for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url

I would like to apologize if this is a million time asked question but I haven't fund my solution yet.

I have a website (build with wordpress), and I would like to change the link structure for logged in users.

For example, If a url is like this http://www.example.com/sample-page , I would like it to be http://www.example.com/sample-page?user_id for logged in users.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The wordpress api has build in functions to check if a user is logged in.

Comment: Hi, I want this because this way each user will have a unique url to share and I could track the urls shared.

Comment: Is it possible to be done?